# Find the area of the marked area in MATLAB image processing

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I applied the wiener filter and then used canny edge detector for the cracks. Now I want to find the whole area affected by cracks (It's not the area of white pixels only but also the Surroundings which is marked in yellow in figure below)

[image]

Comment: I wouldt be able to do that by hand myself. what is the criteria for choosign the area?

Comment: @David - to expand upon Ander's comment - could you provide a simple test case which includes: 1) A matrix for the "image" (e.g. a `logical` array of say 10x10 pixels representing black/white regions); 2) A matrix of the same size representing the yellow line; 3) The desired output using 1) & 2)?

Comment: It is just that we not only need the cracks but the area surrounding the cracks,say a rectangular area which consists all the cracks

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting only cracks in your final binary image you can try few tricks for an approximate calculation of area, it is quite simple technique but may be work for your problem.

1) Find-out x and y indices of all white pixels(in MATLAB find() command will do it), then find out mean of x and y coordinates i.e. centroid of all white pixels in image, now you can find distance of all white pixels from the centroids 
as:

`d = sqrt((x-xc).^2+(y-yc).^2)`

above will give you a distance array of all whites corresponding to center of mass of whites, find out the maximum distance and choose that distance as the radius of an imaginary circle. now just find out area of this circle.

2) If you are getting your structures as different blobs, extract out bounding box of each blob and calculate area of each bounding box and add all the areas.

3) One more way is to calculating ellipse area of blobs. which you can get from major and minor axes, add area of all ellipses.

4) There are also some complex techniques to deal with this problem such as Convex Hull. you can find out convex hull from `regionprops`, this will give you convex hull area for each blob.

Answer (score 0):

It's not 100% clear to me how you define the 'area affected by the cracks', but based on your sketch it could be the convex hull of the crack image. So, starting from a binary image of the edges:

```
[X,Y]  = find(edges);
[~,area] = convhull(X,Y)
```

Of course, unless those straight lines near the top of your image are to be counted as cracks as well, they would first need to be removed from `edges` somehow.